# Parse: PFUser subclassed object not updating attributes across viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, singleton

I'm subclassing the PFUser with a User class. It is registered correctly with Parse.

User.h

```
@interface User : PFUser <PFSubclassing>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *topics;
```

User.m

```
@interface User ()
@end
@implementation User
@synthesize topics;
```

In a view controller, I access the user with:

```
User *user = [User currentUser];
user.topics = @[@"a"];
```

and in subsequent view controller I run this code:

```
User *user = [User currentUser];
user.topics = [user.topics addObject:@"b"];
```

When I pop back to the first view controller, if I check user.topics in the viewDidLoad it shows that its value is still 
    [@"a"]
and not
    [@"a", @"b"]

The [User currentUser] fetches a singleton, which theoretically should change no matter where I edit it from.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have registered your subclass in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` before calling your keys, all thats recommended you change is your synthesized property. You should call `@dynamic` as opposed to synthesized. Source : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-properties-amp-methods

Comment: Thanks Jteve - I actually don't want that particular attribute to be saved up on to parse, which is why I'm using synthesize instead of dynamic. Either way, I tried changing it to dynamic still no dice. When I looked at the pointer, they are the same address in both places. However, in the description it is showing that it is a PFUser object and not a User object - could that be why? Not sure why I'd be able to read but not write properties though.